# Insert Data into Excel File generated using Excel PIA's

Tags: sql-server, excel, interop, office-pia

I have generated excel file using Excel 2007 PIA's and now I want to insert data from database into excel file.I am having SQL Server 2005 database.I also want to format the data in excel file.

Guide me..
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you using [NPOI](http://npoi.codeplex.com/releases/view/49524) to do the excel stuff. it's light-weight, and can do all the data inserting and formatting as you expected.

Comment: just checkout the examples in the example package.